# why this regex from git ls-remote is not working as it should be?

Tags: regex, git, grep, sh

if I do :

`echo From ssh://azeaze@azaz.git | grep -oh From.* | grep -oh ssh.*git`

I get what is excepted, which is:

`ssh://azeaze@azaz.git`

but if I do:

`git ls-remote | grep -oh From.* | grep -oh ssh.*git`

I get the following output:

`From ssh://azeaze@azaz.git`

### Why?

Comment: Please post the relevant line that's coming out from the `git ls-remote` command.

Comment: Also hope that there's never a  `refs/heads/restartFromScratch` in the list of remote branches ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "from" line goes to stderr, so it's ignored by grep. Redirect stderr to stdout to pipe it to grep:

```
git ls-remote 2>&1 | grep -o 'From.*' | grep -o 'ssh.*git'
```

Minor changes: `-h` is not needed when grepping stdin. Patterns quoted to prevent wildcard expansion by the shell.

Comment: Since they grep out everything that normally goes to stdout, they might even discard that entirely: `git ls-remote 2>&1 1>/dev/null | grep -oh ssh.git`.

Comment: Furthermore please quote the string You are searching for: `*` is a wildcard character that can be expanded to the actual contents of the working directory.

Comment: Why does it go to the `stderr`?

Comment: Because https://github.com/git/git/blob/83232e38648b51abbcbdb56c94632b6906cc85a6/builtin/ls-remote.c#L127

Comment: That's still confusing because according to OP's code, the second snippet shouldn't have printed anything, because the first `grep` shouldn't match at all, and an "empty" output should be piped to the second one. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Maroun: only stdout is piped through the greps. stderr is printed entirely unfiltered.